# C# Automapper: Nullable Boolean Not working for different Class member names

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, automapper

Automapper is not mapping correctly between two boolean nullable members, with different names.
This Always results in Null in the destination. How can this be resolved?

```
CreateMap<{Product, ProductDto>()
     .ForMember(dest => dest.ProductStatus, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Status))
     .ReverseMap();
```

Being called like this,

```
var productList = _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<ProductDto>, IEnumerable<Product>>(productDtoList);


public class ProductDto
{
    public int ProductId{ get; set; }
    public string ProductName{ get; set; }
    public bool? ProductStatus { get; set; }
} 

public class Product
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public bool? Status { get; set; }
}
```

Update: It seems to be working though, when I name both ProductDto and Product as `Status`, instead of `ProductStatus` on ProductDto

Currently using Net Core 3.1

Comment: Need more information like the `Queue` and `QueueDto` classes and how you are calling it.

Comment: both are nullable booleans in source and destination, edited to show how its being called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a quick console app and everything worked as expected, so I'm not sure what the problem is. Make sure your configuration is actually being applied to your `_mapper`. I can only guess that might be the problem.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var configuration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg
            .CreateMap<Product, ProductDto>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.ProductStatus, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Status))
            .ReverseMap()
        );

        var mapper = new Mapper(configuration);

        var productDtoList = new List<ProductDto>
        {
            new ProductDto { ProductId = 0, ProductName = "Product 1", ProductStatus = false },
            new ProductDto { ProductId = 1, ProductName = "Product 2", ProductStatus = true },
            new ProductDto { ProductId = 2, ProductName = "Product 3", ProductStatus = null },
        };

        var productList = mapper.Map<List<Product>>(productDtoList);

        foreach(var product in productList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{product.ProductId}\t{product.ProductName}\t{product.Status}");
            // Output
            // 0    Product 1   False
            // 1    Product 2   True
            // 2    Product 3   
        }
    }
}

public class ProductDto
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public bool? ProductStatus { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public bool? Status { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I think there might be another issue. I changed my answer.

Comment: I apologize, I also have reverse map in the bottom, what I gave above is the whole thing now

Comment: I updated my answer with a sample that works as intended.

Comment: it seems to be working though, when I name both Dto and entity status, instead of productstatus on DTO

Comment: Is your mapping configuration being applied to your `_mapper` correctly? Are you using dependency injection for that? I'm wondering if that's where the issue is.

Comment: I gave points, I just renamed, my configuration match up, but anyways, due credit appreciate the review

Comment: It'll work by convention without a configuration if all the property names are the same.